# What are the minimum member of bits required to distinguish 108 distinct objects?

Tags: combinatorics, binary

This is a question in a book written by reputed author RP Jain named Modern Digital Electronics where he answers the above as 8 but whereas simple logic tells 128 distinct objects can be distinguished just by 7 bits.

Then why is the answer 8 bits?

Comment: Could you provide a direct quote with a bit of context? 108 seems such a random number that I wonder whether there's a typo in the book, and more context might give hints in that direction.

Answer (score -1):

usually electronic devices have bits in powers of 2, thus 2 , 4, 8, 16, 32, and 64 bits. You cannot have a 7 bit machine. You are true that $2^7 = 128$ can do it. Bur the problem there is no 7-bit electronic device, the closest to your answer is thus 8-bit

Comment: This doesn't ring true to me. I think we would need to see a quote from the book to know whether this is the explanation.

Comment: "You cannot have a 7 bit machine...there is no 7-bit electronic device" false...false.

Comment: In fact, there were computers with variable byte length.